# Проверка массива на пустоту

Tags: c#, массивы

```
public IsFree(byte[] Raw)
{
    if (Raw == null)
        return true;
    foreach (byte b in Raw)
        if (b != 0xFF)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Можно ли сделать проверку короче/красивее? Пустота именно 0xFF

Comment: в `Linq` например есть `all` метод для перечисления. больше вводных! зы: лучше `isEmpty` назовите

Comment: Если длина массива Raw невелика и максимальный размер известен, можно создать второй массив, залитый 0xFF, а для сравнения использовать WinAPI-вызов [`RtlEqualMemory`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlequalmemoryy).

Comment: Просто в порядке извращения, можно воткнуть ассёмблерную вставку с вызовом `repe scasb` или `repne scasb`, возможно, есть WinAPI-обёртка над ней. Но это больше про перфоманс, чем про длину.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var bytes = new byte[] { /*...*/ };
if (bytes.IsEmpty())
{
    //..
}

public static class BytesExtensions
{
    public static bool IsEmpty(this byte[] source, byte value = 0xFF)
    {
        return source == null || source.All(x => x == value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень плохое решение **только** из-за использования значения по-умолчанию. Метод расширения, который будет доступен во всём проекте, с названием IsEmpty() без параметров ни разу не соответствует реализации и вводит пользователя в заблуждение.

Comment: public bool IsEmpty => (Raw == null || Raw.All(b => b == 0xFF)); // вот так вот я сделал

Comment: @KtoTo  `bool IsEmpty = Raw?.All(b => (b==0xFF))??false;`

Comment: @Alias так вернее будет `bool IsEmpty = Raw?.All(x => x==0xFF)??true;`

Comment: @Alias так красивее и минималистичнее, но сложнее читается. На столько сложнее, что сам допустил ошибку

Comment: @pavelip  точно, спс)

Comment: @KtoTo  именно, так сложнее для восприятия, и вы хотели *сделать проверку короче/красивее*, как ещё лучше я не знаю. Пардон, торопился :)